# Am I able to save my matplotlib.pyplot plot to a variable to use it on a Dash app?

Tags: python

So this is the code:

```
analyzer.data['Inpatient Beds Occupied by COVID-19 Patients Estimated'] = analyzer.data['Inpatient Beds Occupied by COVID-19 Patients Estimated'].str.replace(',', '')
analyzer.data['Inpatient Beds Occupied by COVID-19 Patients Estimated'] = pd.to_numeric(analyzer.data['Inpatient Beds Occupied by COVID-19 Patients Estimated'])
#Group the data by date and calculate the mean value for each date
data = analyzer.data.groupby('date')['Inpatient Beds Occupied by COVID-19 Patients Estimated'].mean()

'''Create a  time series plot is created using matplotlib to visualize the trend of the estimated inpatient beds occupied by COVID-19 patients over time'''

plt.plot(data.index, data.values)
plt.xlabel('Date',fontdict={'fontsize': 9})
plt.ylabel('Estimated Inpatient Beds Occupied by COVID-19 Patients',fontdict={'fontsize': 9})
plt.title('Time Series Analysis of Estimated Inpatient Beds Occupied by COVID-19 Patients',fontdict={'fontsize': 10})
plt.xticks(fontsize=5)
plt.yticks(fontsize=8)

try:
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'plot.png'))
    print("\nImage saved")
except:
    print("file is in directory")
    plt.show()
```

So I want to use the plot I generated into a Dash app, using something like this:

```
dcc.Graph(
    id='example-graph',
    figure=plot
    )
```

I watched a video on how to make a Dash app (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4N10pGNatPg) but they used plotly.express. So am I able to use matplotlib.pyplot or do I need to convert to  plotly.express?

I tried looking online for resources but couldnt find much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use plotly in order to get the same output to be displayed on the Dash app from what I know which can be wrapped around matplotlib library.

```
import plotly.matplotlylib as mpl_plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# Convert the Matplotlib plot to a Plotly figure
plotly_fig = mpl_plotly.mpl_to_plotly(plt.gcf())

# Update the layout of the Plotly figure to match the Matplotlib plot
plotly_fig.update_layout(
    title='Time Series Analysis of Estimated Inpatient Beds Occupied by COVID-19 Patients',
    xaxis_title='Date',
    yaxis_title='Estimated Inpatient Beds Occupied by COVID-19 Patients',
    font=dict(size=10),
)

# Use the Plotly figure in a Dash app
dcc.Graph(
    id='example-graph',
    figure=plotly_fig
)
```

Most likely this should get the desired image output in the Dash app if the syntax is correct.